# azure sql dynamic data masking multiple policies or groups

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-masking, dynamic-data-masking

I'm trying to use the Dynamic data masking in Azure SQL database.
What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to have multiple masking policies for multiple AAD groups.

For example a table has 4 columns and I have 3 AAD groups:

- Group 1 should see data from column 1 and 2 but mask column 3 and 4
- Group 2 should see data from column 1,2 and 3 but mask column 4
- Group 3 should see all data

I'm not sure if this is even possible at all. Is there anyone who can help me?

Kind regards

Comment: It looks like Microsoft have recently made an announcement on more granular permissions for `UNMASK` but I can't find the documentation on it just now:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/azure-sql-news-update-april-2021/ba-p/2257878

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no granularity for the UNMASK permission in SQL Server, either we can see all masked data as masked or unmasked, depends on whether they have UNMASK granted.

Check this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230820/how-to-grant-unmask-permission-to-a-user-at-table-level-and-column-level-in-sql)